# how to add images when exporting in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, image, highcharts

I want to know how to add images while exporting the image from highcharts. i dont want the images to be "on" the highchart images but i want it to display like this...

```
<"IMAGE1">

<"CHART">

<"IMAGE2">
```

is it possible and if it is then how? i understand that there is a image renderer in high charts but that is not what i want..

```
renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 100, 100, 30, 30)
.add();​
```

Thanks in advanced.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the renderer.image and pad the top and bottom of the plot with space.  Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/dqhxW/1/):

[image]

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            spacingTop: 90,
            spacingBottom: 90
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]

    }, function(chart) { // on complete

        chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 0, 0, 100, 100)
            .add();  

        chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 0, 500, 100, 100)
            .add();         

    });
});​
```

Comment: I see, so now i know that the image renderer can be used not just to put images "WITHIN" the highchart but paddings can be used for the images not to overlap! thanks!